# Node.js not rendering in index.handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Ive been recently learning how to use node.js to create a backend login system with passport. Im running it locally with a mongoDB. The url I use to access it is http://localhost:3000. Now when I go to that url instead of displaying my index.handlebars page it routes me to http://localhost:3000/users/login. Im  wondering why this is? Ill provide a few files let me know if there is anything else you may need.

Not sure what else you would need, but I have looked through my code hundreds of times and cant find out why. My routes seem fine, my static folder seems fine. Im just lost. Any help would be appreciated.

My directory looks like this,

```
loginapp-master
-models
 -users.js
-node_modules
-public
 -css
 -fonts
 -js
-routes
 -index.js
 -users.js
-views
 -layouts
  -layout.handlebars
 -index.handlebars
 -login.handlebars
 -register.handlebars
.gitignore
app.js
package-lock.json
package.json



var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// Init App
var app = express();

// View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout:'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: true
}));

// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});



app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// Set Port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server started on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Because of this line:  app.use('/users', users);  BTW, I used that same tutorial, and you are going to find out it is incomplete.  It doesn't check for duplicates.  It's not case-insensitive where it needs to be, etc.  Just FYI.

Comment: Check for duplicate what exactly? and what is it you mean by case insensitive? As for the issue should it be app.use('/views', users); ?

Comment: You are better off if you modify your router.get() to let it be "users/login," 
"users/register," etc.  That's the whole point of using paths like that.  As regards the duplicates, it doesn't check for duplicate users when registering.  Plus, some people prefer case-insensitive searches for matching user names, etc.

Comment: Ill have to add the functions in order to check for duplicates and make certain thing sensitive and insensitive to cases. Thanks for the heads up. Im not quit fully understanding where your coming from with the router.get(). those are currently in my index.js and my users.js.router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
 res.render('index');
});
That is how they are listed there. You say i should switch the '/' to '/users/login' on there?

Comment: What I am saying is don't access it here:   http://localhost:3000.  Access it here:   http://localhost:3000/users/login.  Put that in your browser.  If you want to access something at  http://localhost:3000, then, you do that in your index.js router.

Comment: Im just trying to access my index page at all. index.handlebars As of right now yes I can access register and login by putting in that url. But I want a sort of landing page which would be index.handlebars

Comment: Been a while since I was in that tutorial.  As I recall, many of the routes invoke ensureAuthenticated middleware, which redirects you to users/login if it detects that a user is not yet logged in.  Look at ensureAuthenticated.

Comment: Your right lol Im a moron thanks for your help with my retardation.!!